# asp.net - giving variable to button then passing it to modal

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have a 3x3 squares with a total of 9 and each of them must be filled with an employee (Printing ID) there is a button for each box and when clicked, a modal will display for the display of all the employee. here it is

```
<div class="panel-heading">
  8 //number 8 box
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
 <div class="form-group input-group">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
   <button class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
     <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
   </button>
  </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

After clicking the button a modal will appear and a list of employee will display via table(using SQL), there is a button also there that would do the action and put the chosen employee's information to the box designated (number 8 in this case). How can I put something like a `unique id` for each box so when the button for the 3x3 is clicked their `unique id` will be read and the back code will know where to throw the information?